# WinError2 keeps popping up with this python 3.7.3 script to delete files in a file tree without having to scroll through them

Tags: python-3.x, delete-file

I am REALLY (2 days) new to all of this. I am trying to delete a bunch of files in a folder in my external HD with a python 3.7.3 script but an error keeps popping up.

Firstly, this code works fine and finds the folders:

```
import os
for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk("D:\Practice"):
for filename in filenames:
   if filename.endswith('practice.docx'):
      #os.unlink(filename)
       print(filename)
```

But then when I remove the print(filename) the remove the hash, the folders can't be deleted with the following error popping up:

```
import os
   for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk("D:\Practice"):
   for filename in filenames:
      if filename.endswith('practice.docx'):
      os.unlink(filename)
```

> os.unlink(filename) FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'rootpractice.docx'

The 'rootpractice' doc is clearly recognised but won't be deleted.

Does anyone know how I can solve this? Any help for this total beginner is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.unlink` and similar other methods which require file paths expect either a link relative to current folder in which your script is running (which you can find out with `os.getcwd()` ), or the full path.

When you are iterating with `os.walk`, you are only passing the filename and not the full path. Try this:

```
import os
for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk("D:\Practice"):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('practice.docx'):
            full_path = os.path.join(folderName, filename)
            print("About to delete the file: {}".format(full_path))
            os.unlink(full_path)
```